# SweetAlert2 & Vanilla JS adding an EventListener to multiple buttons that has the same className?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to display **Sweet Alert** popup using **Vanilla JS** I have multiple buttons that has the same **class Name** while I clicked on it automatically the **Sweet Alert** popup will be displayed.

**Here is my JS Code :**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var exampleButton = document.getElementsByClassName("my-btn");
    exampleButton .addEventListener("click", function () {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Thank you!",
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500,
        });
    });
})();
```

**Here is my HTML Code :**

```
<button type="button" class="my-button">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="my-button">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" class="my-button">Button 3</button>
<button type="button" class="my-button">Button 4</button>
<button type="button" class="my-button">Button 5</button>
```

Comment: your question isn't clear , maybe if I got you, your problem that you have to handle "exampleButton" as an array not element

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns a NodeList. You can loop a NodeList using 'forEach' or you can use Array.from() to transform it into a real Array.
Then you have to loop for each button and attach the event to it.

````js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    const exampleButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("my-btn");
    Array.from(exampleButtons).forEach(btn => {
       btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
         Swal.fire({
            icon: "success",
            title: "Thank you!",
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500,
         });
    });
   });
})();
```
````

Comment: it show Up when I reload the page normally it should display only if I clicked on the button ?

Comment: with this code, the alert appears only when a button with class `my-btn` is clicked. If something happens on reload probably `Swal.fire();` is called somewhere else

Comment: what I want to achieve is clear I have mutiple buttons with the same classname when I clicked to one of them step by step it should display the same SweatAlert popup

Comment: I have created a JSFiddle to show how the code works, hope it can help :) 
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ydae23xb/)